# Unknown activation function in r

Tags: r, neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrXDT.png)I am working in r. I need to fir a neural network that will contain four levels of output. Below is the code that I wrote:

```
wifiLocDat <- read.table("wifi_localization.txt")
colnames(wifiLocDat) <- c('Wifi1','Wifi2','Wifi3','Wifi4','Wifi5','Wifi6','Wifi7','Room')

#Classifying Rooms into 4 categories
Room = c(1,2,3,4)
Loc1 <- c(Room==1)
Loc2 <- c(Room==2)
Loc3 <- c(Room==3)
Loc4 <- c(Room==4)

df = data.frame(Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4)

library(neuralnet)
nnRes <- neuralnet(Room~Loc1+Loc2+Loc3+Loc4,data=df,hidden=4,act.fct = "logistic",   linear.output = FALSE)
plot(nnRes)
```

I received an error code:

**Error: Unknown activation function.**

Please what do I need to do to fix this?

Sample Data:

```
head(wifiLocDat)
  Wifi1 Wifi2 Wifi3 Wifi4 Wifi5 Wifi6 Wifi7 Room
1   -64   -56   -61   -66   -71   -82   -81    1
2   -68   -57   -61   -65   -71   -85   -85    2
3   -63   -60   -60   -67   -76   -85   -84    3
4   -61   -60   -68   -62   -77   -90   -80    4
5   -63   -65   -60   -63   -77   -81   -87    1
6   -64   -55   -63   -66   -76   -88   -83    2
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, what is your `packageVersion("neuralnet")` ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The package version is 1.44.2. It worked on my machine as well, I need to have four output, but I had just two.

Comment: What do you mean by four output ?

Comment: I added my plot picture to the question. The plan is to have four level of output, and not one like I currently have . I have 4 input, 4 hidden, and I need 4 output.

Comment: Ok then convert Room to factor should produce what you want : `Room = factor(c(1,2,3,4))`

Comment: Thank you Bastien. It worked. Appreciate your time and support.